# Restoring database from file or multiple files

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1

Trying to restore the file or files returned by this statement

```
$backupFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupPath -Filter "*$tstamp*.bak" -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Select-Object
```

I am executing this command. I get a warning and the restore is NOT done.

```
$backupFiles | Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $primaryReplica -useDestinationDefaultDirectories -WithReplace
```

$backupFiles value is below

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-a----         9/8/2022  10:36 PM      130576384 WP04034XXXXX_WebStrat_20220908223605_full.bak
```

The command throws a warning and does not do the restore. The error seems as if the variable being passed is empty, but it's not, so what gives?
See Warning below

```
WARNING: [16:12:02][Restore-DbaDatabase] No backups passed through. 
 This could mean the SQL instance cannot see the referenced files, the file's headers could not be read or some other issue
```

This is the code reference to the PowerShell function being used
[Restore-DbaDatabase](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/0.9.188/Content/functions%5CRestore-DbaDatabase.ps1)

Comment: Is the targeted database instance on a different machine? The error message and the help for the linked function suggest that the input file paths must be local to the machine where the database instance runs.

Comment: Ah it is not.. That must be what it is. The file and database dont reside on the same server. I will run more test but I think this to be the answer.